# Content Porter Error 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, content-porter-2013, sql-server, content-porter-2013-sp1

I am doing content porting activity from UAT to SYS.

While running content importing to SYS a sql exception error occured.

Note: this error occured while importing categories and keywords.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you look closely at the stack trace of your exception, you will see that the exception happens at the `SyncronizeContentWithSchema()` method. This method happens during every import. If you import a Component, it will automatically be validated against the current Schema in the system. The import will fail if a Component is not in sync with schema (for example, missing some mandatory field values, has some extra fields, etc.).

To fix this, please analyze what are the changes on the Schema that are disabling your Component from being imported.

Comment: I have imported by selecting small packages like first components, assets and categories one by one  while following this approach didn't face any issue